# How can I use url variable as url request?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use my variable 'real url' to url request.
I declared real url in app delegate like this:

```
AppDeleGate.swift:

import ...

..
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var realurl : URL?
..
```

And, I want to use that url in `DetailController`

```
DetailController.swift:

...
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(ad?.realurl)!)
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.load(request)
...
```

but error... in ad?.realurl
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Jdn.png)

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let request = URLRequest(url:ad.realurl!)
```

Answer (score 2):

realurl is already an optional url, why are you converting `URL(ad?.realurl)!)`?

```
    let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    if  let url = ad?.realurl  {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.load(request)
    }
```